# Runtime Error Line Number in QTP11(VBScript)

Tags: vbscript, qtp

Is there any way through which I can get the Current Line in QTP or the Runtime Error Line number? The Error Line Number is displayed on QTP Error Popup, so there must be some way through which we can get the error line number....

Comment: Can somebody please help me out with this? Please

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? If the line number can be viewed in the error pop-up, what do you need it for outside of that pop-up?

Comment: In fact there is no piratical use of finding the error line number. You can run the code in debug mode to find exactly on which line the error occurs. Try syntax checker in QTP which also specifies the error line if there is any issue with the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The line number information is not accessible, as far as the QTP community knows.